# How PhantomJS is able to execute Javascript?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, webkit

I read that PhantomJS uses WebKit but isn't WebKit only for HTML/CSS rendering?

```
$ phantomjs
phantomjs> console.log("Hello")
Hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebKit is not only for HTML rendering. It also includes JavaScriptCore for executing JavaScript.

PhantomJS uses QtWebKit, which is based on a very old version of WebKit, including an old JavaScriptCore.